# How to return double Quote to \" in python?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I want to change this dict:

```
{"entityMap": {}, "blocks": [{"key": "", "text": "Testing", "type": "unstyled", "depth": 0, "inlineStyleRanges": [], "entityRanges": [], "data": {}}]}
```

into this :

```
{\"entityMap\": {}, \"blocks\": [{\"key\": \"\", \"text\": \"Testing\", \"type\": \"unstyled\", \"depth\": 0, \"inlineStyleRanges\": [], \"entityRanges\": [], \"data\": {}}]}
```

I've tried this method:

json.dumps()

but the result is a double backslash

```
{\\"entityMap\\": {}, \\"blocks\\": [{\\"key\\": \\"\\", \\"text\\": \\"Testing\\", \\"type\\": \\"unstyled\\", \\"depth\\": 0, \\"inlineStyleRanges\\": [], \\"entityRanges\\": [], \\"data\\": {}}]}
```

How to achieve this in python?

Comment: Could you give us [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: it is working. - That is th expectd output - Python represents "\" in strings with a double \\ to mean an actual \ character, and not that it is escaping something els.  Just see use `print(json.dumps(...))` to see what you actually got.

Comment: I need the exact value as in the "print" value, I can do this in this converter https://codebeautify.org/json-escape-unescape, but I don't know how to make it happen in python